# Regex Expression to validate that the words "OR" and "AND" follow every other word

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regex expression to validate that a string has the words "OR" and "AND" in between each word. The user can also have quotes around words so it needs to follow the quotes as well. Also, the end of the string cannot be OR/AND.

For example, these are valid:

```
dog OR cat AND dog
"Dog" OR cat
cat OR dog AND "bob"
```

These strings are invalid:

```
Dog or cat and dog
dog OR CAT OR
```

Note that OR/AND need to be capitalized.

I am fairly new to Regex so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the first word, then match zero or more combination of AND/OR keywords + word.

```
^\S+(?: (?:OR|AND) \S+)*$
```

Regex Explanation:

- `^`: start of string
- `\S+`: any non-space character
- `(?: (?:OR|AND) \S+)+`: "*AND*"/"*OR*" followed by non-space characters
- `$`: end of string

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ob98Zi/2).

Note: if you want to force at least the presence of one AND/OR, then you need to change the final `*` with the `+`.

Comment: This matches a string that doesn't contain AND or OR, it doesn't account for _"the end of the string cannot be OR/AND"_. Also, I'm not sure whether or not something like "@@@ AND ###" would be an acceptable match by the OP, given that it's unclear what is meant to be a "word".

Comment: For a more restrictive word detection, you should look into changing `\S+`, which is responsible for gathering generic non-space characters. If you know that you can have only words made of alphanumeric characters and quotes, you can use `[a-z"]+` instead.